# Exception "AES: 4 is not a valid key length" on BegleboneBlack

Tags: encryption, beagleboneblack, crypto++

I installed Crypto++ on BeagleBone black by following native installation method provided at [ARM (Command Line)](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Arm_(Command_Line)). Then when I ran `cryptest.sh`, it runs smoothly.

Here is my small test-code to test Crypto++ functionality.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "libcryptoWrapperGCM.h"
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    byte key[]  = "123456789012345";
    byte vi[]   = "123456789012345";
    char p[205] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09,   
         0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x05, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x6e, 0xf0, 0x01, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00,    
         0x06, 0x70, 0x61, 0x72, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x31, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x06, 0x70, 0x61, 0x72, 0x61, 0x6d,   
         0x32, 0xf0, 0x02, 0x00, 0xa0, 0x00, 0x23, 0x00, 0x40, 0x38, 0x34, 0x32, 0x33, 0x32, 0x30, 0x33,    
         0x34, 0x62, 0x66, 0x61, 0x36, 0x38, 0x38, 0x32, 0x38, 0x30, 0x64, 0x37, 0x36, 0x38, 0x35, 0x64,   
         0x39, 0x66, 0x62, 0x62, 0x65, 0x36, 0x34, 0x32, 0x37, 0x36, 0x37, 0x36, 0x33, 0x34, 0x61, 0x64, 
         0x36, 0x34, 0x37, 0x32, 0x66, 0x66, 0x37, 0x33, 0x63, 0x33, 0x34, 0x32, 0x65, 0x63, 0x34, 0x32,  
         0x35, 0x38, 0x31, 0x35, 0x37, 0x66, 0x61, 0x33, 0x61, 0x00, 0x24, 0x00, 0x40, 0x36, 0x35, 0x30,    
         0x38, 0x63, 0x39, 0x31, 0x36, 0x63, 0x37, 0x39, 0x30, 0x63, 0x66, 0x37, 0x33, 0x34, 0x61, 0x31,    
         0x64, 0x34, 0x35, 0x65, 0x30, 0x32, 0x62, 0x30, 0x64, 0x39, 0x61, 0x39, 0x65, 0x37, 0x35, 0x36,    
         0x37, 0x34, 0x66, 0x36, 0x64, 0x61, 0x62, 0x31, 0x63, 0x61, 0x30, 0x32, 0x64, 0x31, 0x64, 0x66,    
         0x64, 0x37, 0x39, 0x63, 0x66, 0x39, 0x35, 0x38, 0x35, 0x64, 0x36, 0x31, 0x33, 0x00, 0x25, 0x00,    
         0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x57, 0x16, 0x69, 0x13, 0x00, 0x26, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,    
         0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x0b, 0x94};
    char *p_data_ptr = p; 
    byte *ebuffer = malloc(205+12);
    char *d = GcmEncode(key,vi, p_data_ptr,205,ebuffer,0);
    int i ;
    for(i=0; i< 205+12; i++){
        printf("0x%02x, ",ebuffer[i] & 0xff);
    }
    char *buffer = malloc(205);

    char* decodedMessage = GcmDecode(key, vi,ebuffer, 217,buffer,0);

    return 1;
}
```

When I run the program I get Exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::InvalidKeyLength'
  what():  AES: 4 is not a valid key length
Aborted
```

The odd thing is that it only happens on BeagleBone Black and not x86 machine, even though both have Ubuntu 14.04.

Any idea how to solve this issue? Thank you.

Edit 1:
Here is the wrapper source:

```
 #include "gcm.h"

 using CryptoPP::GCM;


 #include "assert.h"

 extern "C" {
     const char* GcmEncode(byte key_hash[],byte iv_hash[], byte*  p_data_ptr,size_t length,uint8_t* destination, int offset) {
         string cipher,encoded;
         encoded.clear();
         GCM< AES >::Encryption e;
         e.SetKeyWithIV( key_hash, sizeof(key_hash), iv_hash, sizeof(iv_hash) );
         const int TAG_SIZE = 16;
         StringSource(p_data_ptr,length, true,
                 new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter( e,
                     new StringSink( cipher ), false, TAG_SIZE)
                 );
         encoded.clear();

         StringSource(cipher, true,
                 new HexEncoder(new StringSink( encoded ))
                 );
         memcpy(&(destination[offset]),cipher.c_str(),length+12);
         return cipher.c_str();//NEED TO BE FREED IN FOLLOWING METHOD

     }
     const char *GcmDecode(byte key_hash[], byte iv_hash[], byte *cipher_ptr,size_t length,  uint8_t* destination, int offset){
         size_t pLength = length - 16;
         string rpdata;
         const int TAG_SIZE = 16;
         GCM< AES >::Decryption d;
         d.SetKeyWithIV(key_hash, sizeof(key_hash), iv_hash, sizeof(iv_hash));
         AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter df(d,new StringSink( rpdata ),
                 AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::DEFAULT_FLAGS,
                 TAG_SIZE
                 );
         StringSource(cipher_ptr,length, true,new Redirector(df));
         bool b = df.GetLastResult();
         if( true == b ){
             memcpy(&(destination[offset]),rpdata.c_str(),pLength);
             return NULL;//NEED TO BE FREED IN FOLLOWING METHOD
         }
         else{
             return NULL;
         }
     }

 }
```

And this is the valgrind output:

```
==26349== 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::InvalidKeyLength'
  what():  AES: 4 is not a valid key length
==26349== 
==26349== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26349==     in use at exit: 462 bytes in 6 blocks
==26349==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 5 frees, 562 bytes allocated
==26349== 
==26349== LEAK SUMMARY:
==26349==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26349==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26349==      possibly lost: 201 bytes in 3 blocks
==26349==    still reachable: 261 bytes in 3 blocks
==26349==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26349== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==26349== 
==26349== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==26349== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Aborted
ubuntu@arm:/home/otocn/Daemon$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out 
==26350== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==26350== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==26350== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==26350== Command: ./a.out
==26350== 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::InvalidKeyLength'
  what():  AES: 4 is not a valid key length
==26350== 
==26350== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26350==     in use at exit: 462 bytes in 6 blocks
==26350==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 5 frees, 562 bytes allocated
==26350== 
==26350== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 6
==26350==    at 0x482E9E0: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:318)
==26350==    by 0x4C85191: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26350==    by 0x4C86289: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26350==    by 0x4C86569: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26350==    by 0x49BA727: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (cryptlib.cpp:52)
==26350==    by 0x49BA727: _GLOBAL__sub_I.00276_cryptlib.cpp (cryptlib.cpp:939)
==26350==    by 0x400B19D: call_init (dl-init.c:78)
==26350==    by 0x400B22F: _dl_init (dl-init.c:126)
==26350==    by 0x4000BF1: ??? (in /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.19.so)
==26350== 
==26350== 45 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 4 of 6
==26350==    at 0x482E9E0: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:318)
==26350==    by 0x4C85191: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26350==    by 0x4C859E5: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26350==    by 0x4C85A57: std::string::reserve(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26350==    by 0x4C85C13: std::string::append(char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26350==    by 0x49C4663: append (basic_string.h:1009)
==26350==    by 0x49C4663: operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > (basic_string.h:2406)
==26350==    by 0x49C4663: CryptoPP::InvalidKeyLength::InvalidKeyLength(std::string const&, unsigned int) (simple.h:50)
==26350==    by 0x49C2E2D: CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::ThrowIfInvalidKeyLength(unsigned int) (cryptlib.cpp:119)
==26350==    by 0x49C2E79: CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::SetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&) (cryptlib.cpp:102)
==26350==    by 0x4A23D8D: CryptoPP::GCM_Base::SetKeyWithoutResync(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&) (gcm.cpp:138)
==26350==    by 0x49C8F41: CryptoPP::AuthenticatedSymmetricCipherBase::SetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&) (authenc.cpp:53)
==26350==    by 0x49C2CB3: CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::SetKeyWithIV(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (cryptlib.cpp:113)
==26350==    by 0x49BAAB7: GcmEncode (in /home/otocn/Daemon/libcryptoc.so)
==26350== 
==26350== 140 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5 of 6
==26350==    at 0x482E358: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:296)
==26350==    by 0x4C46081: __cxa_allocate_exception (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26350== 
==26350== LEAK SUMMARY:
==26350==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26350==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26350==      possibly lost: 201 bytes in 3 blocks
==26350==    still reachable: 261 bytes in 3 blocks
==26350==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26350== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==26350== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==26350== 
==26350== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==26350== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Aborted
```

Comment: Valid key lengths are 16, 24 and 32 byte. Your key is 15 characters long in ASCII, so it is 15 bytes long. Also, a GCM IV (actually nonce) is supposed to be 12 byte long according to the standard.

Comment: *"Then when I ran `cryptest.sh`, it runs smoothly ..."* - That's a thorough but painful script. How long does it take to run on your BBB?

Comment: *`terminate called after throwing an instance of CryptoPP::InvalidKeyLength'. what():  AES: 4 is not a valid key length`* - We need to see your call to `SetKeyWithIV`. Artjom was correct about the 15 byte key; but that does not explain the 4 byte key causing the exception.

Comment: @jww it took almost 2 days

Comment: @andi99 - Is the `CryptoPP::InvalidKeyLength` encountered during `GcmEncode` or `GcmDecode`? Once you isolate it, con you post the relevant code? You might also try running your program under the Sanitizers or Valgrind. I'm guessing you have a memory error somewhere.

Comment: @jww Well for this code I cannot isolate function (`GcmEncode` or `GcmDecode`) I encounter this exception but I executed another test code from internet which was using crypto++ and I encountered error at `GcmEncode` function. So if you can deduce anything from that? Also I will run it through valgrind and try to modify code. Also if you can suggest any test script to check whether I have functioning crypto++? Thanks.

Comment: @andi99 - *"can suggest any test script to check whether I have functioning Crypto++..."* - `cryptest.sh` is what I use to validate the library before release. If there's anything that provides more assurances, then I am not aware of it :) It sounds like the problem is in the library (or use of the library) providing `GcmEncode` and `GcmDecode`. Shooting from the hip, 32/8 = 4. Maybe the library wants the keys size in bits, not bytes, so that 256/8 = 32, which is what Crypto++ expects.

Comment: @jww I changed `byte key[]  = "1234567890123456"
    byte vi[]   = "123456789012" ` to comply with 16 byte key and 12 byte IV standard, but same error. I have specified key to be in bytes and not bits.

Comment: @jww in fact if I write cout debug message as a first line of libcryptoWrapper.cpp, it does not print out anything. So I think problem may be in the way I am building and linking. Here is the script, `'g++ -O0  -I/home/otocn/cryptopp -c -fPIC libcryptoWrapperGCM.cpp -o libcryptoWrapperGCM.o -lcryptopp -lpthread -lrt -lc  && 
g++ -shared -fPIC libcryptoWrapperGCM.o -o libcryptoc.so -Wl,-whole-archive -lcryptopp -lpthread -lrt -lc -Wl,-no-whole-archive  && 
gcc -o test testC.c  -lcryptoc` Anything wrong here?

Comment: You should also add either (1) `-Wl,-rpath,/home/otocn/cryptopp` to `CXXFLAGS`; or (2) `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/home/otocn/cryptopp:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ./test` during runtime. Also see [GNUmakefile | Creating Programs](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/GNUmakefile#Creating_Programs) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: @jww I have already added `/home/otocn/cryptopp` path to `ld.so.conf`. In fact I can compile using distro's copy of library headers as well and I do not need to add -I flag. Do you think I am getting this error because ARM is 32 bit and x86 is 64 bit? I compiled AE c++ code given here [link](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/GCM_Mode) without problem. Thanks.

Comment: @andi99 - I don't believe ARMv7 vs x86_64 is a problem. I actively test it; see [Release Process | CPU and Platform Mashup](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Release_process#The_Mashup) on the wiki. I think you are on the right track with compile/link. Use `ldd` on your program to see what it is linking against.